# About Kitaev p-wave superconductor model and Majorana Zero mode

Tags: majorana-fermions, topological-phase

The Kitaev $p$-wave spinless superconductor model has Hamiltonian as
$$H = \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} tc_j^\dagger c_{j+1} + \Delta c_jc_{j+1} + h.c. + \sum_{j=1}^N \mu c_j^\dagger c_j $$
which has topological phase when $t, \Delta, \mu$ in a regime. In particular, the example of $t=\Delta, \mu=0$ is somehow the most "topological", and therefore great to demonstrate the localized edge Majorana zero mode, for if we diagonalize the Hamiltonian (in principle it's a quadratic form so we can diagonalize it simply), we found that $[(c_1+c_1^\dagger), H]=0$ and $[(ic_N-ic_N^\dagger), H]=0$. This means there are two zero-energy modes and they are only on the edge. The "wave function", or by other means, the component amplitude of the ground state mode operator on each sites, is strongly localized.

On the other hand, however, when we apply exact diagonalization in the total $2^N$ Hilbert space, we could soon find out that in this particular parameter choice ($t=\Delta, \mu=0$), the electron occupation number on ground state $\langle c_j^\dagger c_j\rangle$ is flat, i.e., equal at all sites.

So why these two results so contradict to each other?

Comment: It's the *single-particle* states corresponding to the Majorana modes which are "localized", not the many-body ground state.

Comment: @DominicElse thank you but could you be more specific on this? Can you give me another example to demonstrate the difference?

Comment: What does the sentence "The "wave function", or by other means, the component amplitude of the ground state mode operator on each sites, is strongly localized." mean ? Imagine you got a ground state, write it $\left|\phi\right\rangle $, the property $\left[c_{1}+c_{1}^{\dagger},H\right]=0$, just means that $\left(c_{1}+c_{1}^{\dagger}\right)\left|\phi\right\rangle $ is also a ground state : you found a symmetry of the system. What seems to be localised is $\left(c_{1}+c_{1}^{\dagger}\right)\left|\phi\right\rangle $, not $\left|\phi\right\rangle $.

Comment: @FraSchelle The one you thought should be localized is actually equally flat as the ground state.

Comment: @FraSchelle and as for the sentence, it's a little bit hard to explain... Consider many-body localization on spin chain case where we expand Hamiltonian around site $i$, the exponentially decay amplitude of some particular operator form characterizes the localization. For example, see 1408.4297 equation (1) and comments below. So I call it "wave function" rather than real wave function; however many authors misuse this term.

Comment: @RoderickLee the statements that the operator for the Majorana mode, $c_1 + c_1^{\dagger}$ is localized, and that the expectation value of the occupation number is uniform throughout the chain, are not at all in contradiction to one another, indeed they are pretty much completely unrelated. I think you really need to explain better why you think that they are contradictory before anyone can help you.

Comment: @RoderickLee My feeling is that your confusion is somehow related to what it means for "the Majorana mode to be localized". The (localized) Majorana operator transforms you between *different* (degenerate) ground states. The fact that the operator is localized means that these ground states differ only on the edge. It doesn't mean that all the fermions have to be clustered on the edge in the ground state.